# Getting Unable to locate element: error when executing code through POM, The same locator works fine when executed through single main() program

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

I have created a maven project and in one class(in src/main/java) I have designed the PageFactory(which contains functions).And from the src/test/java,I have created the testNG class and trying to call the selectDepartureDate() method present in src/main/java. While executing the program it shows me the error "unable to locate element", Whereas when i use the same locator in a single main() program then it is working perfectly fine. Can someone please help me identifying the issue. The site which I am using is makemytrip(https://www.makemytrip.com/) and trying to select the departure date.

Below is the program in src/test/java where i am calling the function selectDepartureDate() from validateDateSelection().

```
package com.MMT.qa.testcases;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.MMT.qa.base.TestBaseMMT;
import com.MMT.qa.pages.FlightsHomePageMMT;

public class FlightsHomePageMMTTest extends TestBaseMMT {
    FlightsHomePageMMT homePageMMT ;
    public String dateVal = "Sun Jun 28 2020";

    public FlightsHomePageMMTTest() {
        super();
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() {
        initialization();
        homePageMMT = new FlightsHomePageMMT();
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void validateCitySelection() {

        homePageMMT.enterValueOfFromCity();
        homePageMMT.enterValueOfToCity();
        System.out.println("city selection successfull");
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void validateDateSelection() {
        homePageMMT.selectDepartureDate(dateVal);
        System.out.println("Date selection successful");
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

And below is the program in src/main/java where the PageFactory is defined

```
package com.MMT.qa.pages;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import com.MMT.qa.base.TestBaseMMT;

public class FlightsHomePageMMT extends TestBaseMMT {

    //Page Factory - OR for Home page

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id = 'fromCity']")
    WebElement FromCity;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@placeholder = 'From']")
    WebElement FromTextFromCity;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id = 'toCity']")
    WebElement ToCity;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@placeholder = 'To']")
    WebElement FromTextToCity;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//a[contains(text(),'Search')]")
    WebElement SrchBtn;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class = 'fsw_inputBox dates inactiveWidget ']")
    WebElement DepDateSelect;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='DayPicker-Day' and @aria-label = '\"+dateVal+\"']")
    WebElement dateElement;

    public FlightsHomePageMMT() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }


    //Actions

    public void enterValueOfFromCity() {
        FromCity.click();
        FromTextFromCity.sendKeys("Mumbai");
        List <WebElement> listFrom = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@role ='listbox']//li/descendant::div[@class = 'calc60']//p[contains(text(),'Mumbai, India')]"));
        System.out.println(listFrom.size());

        for(int i = 0 ; i<listFrom.size() ; i++) {
            System.out.println(listFrom.get(i).getText());
            if(listFrom.get(i).getText().contains("Mumbai, India")) {
                listFrom.get(i).click();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void enterValueOfToCity() {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",ToCity);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder = 'To']")).sendKeys("tirupati");

        List <WebElement> listTo = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@role ='listbox']//li/descendant::div[@class = 'calc60']//p[contains(text(),'Tirupati, India')]"));
        System.out.println(listTo.size());

        for(int i = 0 ; i<listTo.size() ; i++) {
            System.out.println(listTo.get(i).getText());
            if(listTo.get(i).getText().contains("Tirupati, India")) {
                listTo.get(i).click();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void selectDepartureDate(String dateVal) {
        DepDateSelect.click();
        //String dateVal = "Sun Jun 28 2020";
        //System.out.println("date clicked");
        dateElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='DayPicker-Day' and @aria-label = '"+dateVal+"']"));
        selectDateByJS(driver,dateElement, dateVal);
    }

    public static void selectDateByJS(WebDriver driver,WebElement dateElement, String dateVal) {
        JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver);
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", dateElement);
    }

}
```

Below is the error that I am getting.

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.1
Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882}) on port 39579
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1589036561.334][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 81.
[1589036563.472][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
May 09, 2020 8:32:45 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
[1589036568.052][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[1589036572.590][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589036575.221][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589036576.233][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589036577.088][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589036577.195][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
1
Mumbai, India
1
Tirupati, India
city selection successfull
PASSED: validateCitySelection
FAILED: validateDateSelection
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class = 'fsw_inputBox dates inactiveWidget ']"}
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-1QASA0A', ip: '192.168.1.129', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '14'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 81.0.4044.138, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Ravindra\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:60874}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 5f8863f488b2de8092949619e9d75e0b
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//div[@class = 'fsw_inputBox dates inactiveWidget ']}
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.click(Unknown Source)
    at com.MMT.qa.pages.FlightsHomePageMMT.selectDepartureDate(FlightsHomePageMMT.java:80)
    at com.MMT.qa.testcases.FlightsHomePageMMTTest.validateDateSelection(FlightsHomePageMMTTest.java:34)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 2, Passes: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Below is the HTML dom for the locator.

```html
<div class="fsw_inputBox dates inactiveWidget "><label for="departure"><span class="lbl_input latoBold appendBottom10">DEPARTURE</span><input data-cy="departure" id="departure" type="text" class="fsw_inputField font20" readonly="" value="Friday, 19 Jun 2020"><p data-cy="departureDate" class="blackText font20 code"><span class="font30 latoBlack ">19 </span><span>Jun</span><span class="shortYear">20</span></p><p data-cy="departureDay" class="code">Friday</p></label></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution for the above question. The code is absolutely fine. The only thing which I was missing was, when we select the 'From' and 'To city' then after that the 'Departure' calendar column gets automatically open and there is no need to click on the locator of that 'Departure'. This is the reason why it was giving UnableToLocateElement exception. In the above program I have only removed the line

DepDateSelect.click();

from the function

selectDepartureDate(String dateVal) and it started selecting the date.

Below is the updated code :

```
public void selectDepartureDate() {
        //DepDateSelect.click();
         String dateVal = "Tue Jun 02 2020";
        try {
         WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='DayPicker-Day' and @aria-label = '"+dateVal+"']"));
         selectDateByJS(driver,element);
        }catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println("Date selected by JS");
        }

        }
     public static void selectDateByJS(WebDriver driver,WebElement element) {

            JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver);
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
        }
```